# What are the default ./configuration option for PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

What are the default ./configuration option for PHP?

My basic requirement is PDO and mysql.

What options i need to put in ./configuration ?

yum repo of my linux distribution doesn't support mysql, so i need to compile the PHP source :(

Below is the phpinfo() output when i use yum install php.

'

> ./configure' '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu'
>   '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu'    '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu'
>   '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr'
>   '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc'
>   '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include'
>   '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec'
>   '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/usr/com'
>   '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info'
>   '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--with-libdir=lib64'
>   '--with-config-file-path=/etc'
>   '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d' '--disable-debug'
>   '--with-pic' '--disable-rpath' '--without-pear' '--with-bz2'
>   '--with-curl' '--with-exec-dir=/usr/bin' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr'
>   '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--without-gdbm'
>   '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr'
>   '--with-openssl' '--with-png' '--with-pspell' '--with-expat-dir=/usr'
>   '--with-pcre-regex=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-layout=GNU'
>   '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-magic-quotes'
>   '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm'
>   '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-track-vars' '--enable-trans-sid'
>   '--enable-yp' '--enable-wddx' '--with-kerberos'
>   '--enable-ucd-snmp-hack' '--with-unixODBC=shared,/usr'
>   '--enable-memory-limit' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-calendar'
>   '--enable-dbx' '--enable-dio'
>   '--with-mime-magic=/usr/share/file/magic.mime' '--without-sqlite'
>   '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--with-xml' '--with-system-tzdata'
>   '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' '--without-mysql' '--without-gd'
>   '--without-odbc' '--disable-dom' '--disable-dba' '--without-unixODBC'
>   '--disable-pdo' '--disable-xmlreader' '--disable-xmlwriter'

```
vim mysql.ini
; Enable mysql extension module
extension=mysql.so
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `yum install php-mysql` and see if that adds the MySQL extension to PHP.

You can run `yum search php` to list additional modules you can install into PHP such as `php-gd`, `php-pdo` etc.

Comment: i tired yum install php-mysql but it adds only additional .ini file in php.d directory. yum install php is always installing php without mysql i.e,'--without-mysql'

Comment: Did you stop and then start the apache service after installing php-mysql?  Make sure to do that first

Comment: yes i restarted service httpd restart, still phpinfo() shows ./configure '--without-mysql' and no configuration is present in phpinfo().

Comment: also i have enabled mysql extension in php.ini

Comment: It should work, this tutorial may help: http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-fedora-11-lamp

Comment: drew,i am following same steps mentioned in tutorial, even extension=msql.so is mentioned in php.ini, what could be the problem?

Comment: msql.so is a different extension than mysql, what version of PHP are you ending up with?

Comment: Did you notice any errors or anything when you ran `yum install php-mysql` like maybe it couldn't update some config or something?  If you search in the phpinfo() output you still see no `MySQL` section right?

Comment: yes, no mysql section but after yum install php-mysql additional .ini files parsed row shows /etc/php.d/mysql.ini, /etc/php.d/mysqli.ini,

Comment: should i change extension_dir = "./" to something else?

Comment: extension_dir may need to be changed, see if there is an `extensions` directory in your PHP install path.  Also, if you could, post the contents of `mysql.ini` in the original question.  Typically I compile PHP manually because with 5.1.6 yum is years behind the current version, but this has worked for me in cases where I need a quick install on CentOS.

Comment: i have added mysql.ini content in the question, where should i look for extension ? sorry for asking basic questions

Comment: That's ok.  See if it is located in `extension_dir` which you can see the value of in `phpinfo()`.  If it is not there, the extension_dir may be incorrect.  Otherwise `find / -name mysql.so -print` as root may find where it is installed to.

Comment: find is taking very much time, where should i generally look for extensions or what is the default install path ?

Comment: by simply typing php in command prompt i am getting following: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './msql.so' - ./msql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: finally i got modules directory: /usr/lib64/php/modules

Comment: Thanks a ton, drew, after setting extension_dir = "/usr/lib64/php/modules", mysql is enabled. You helped me alot drew.